# Phalcon pagination break sorting order

Tags: php, sorting, phalcon

After this pagination [Phalcon auto pagination with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763123/phalcon-auto-pagination-with-jquery/38803989?noredirect=1#comment65292928_38803989) find out that query is not rendering its sorting order. and in my controller 
i try like

[Controller]

```
$bloger     = Blogs::find(["order" => "datetime DESC"]);
$numberPage = $this->request->getQuery('page', 'int', 1);
$paginator = new paginator ([
    'data'  => $bloger,
    'limit' => 2,
    "order" => "datetime DESC",
    'page'  => $numberPage
]);
```

But its not following sorting order not asc, not desc, or not random. if i remove order line then its render just ascending order. how to solve? plz

Array output :

```
11 | 2016-07-31 21:12:40
3 | 2016-07-31 01:03:49
1 | 2016-07-31 01:03:30
10 | 2016-07-28 11:07:35
9 | 2016-07-28 02:41:47
6 | 2016-07-26 00:41:11
7 | 2016-07-11 23:25:19
2 | 2016-05-17 23:10:17
8 | 2016-04-16 23:47:26
5 | 2016-04-15 23:18:05
4 | 2016-04-15 23:16:31
```

Comment: The `new paginator` doesn't take the parameter `order`. Can you give us the (array) output of `$bloger`?

Comment: If i echo $bloger it shows error : atchable fatal error: Object of class Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple could not be converted to string in. if i var_dump $bloger output is more large its not possible to paste here.

Comment: do `echo '<pre>', print_r($bloger->toArray()), '</pre>'; die;` And print the output here. We only need **relevant data**, so maybe alter your query to `Blogs::find(["columns" => "id, datetime", "order" => "datetime DESC"])` (only select relevant columns)

Comment: I just test it like  foreach($bloger as $b){echo($b->id.'<br/>');}exit(); and the out put is as follow 11,3,1,10,9,6,7,2,8,5,4

Comment: We need to know the values of `datetime`, because this is the order you are trying to use. (and you claim it doesn't order correctly). Please try to use the code snippet I posted in the comment above !

Comment: print_r($bloger->toA‌​rray()) shows error like : Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple::toA‌​rray() in

Comment: That looks ok to me. What is your output **after** you used the paginator? Can you compare those two please.

Comment: Got it! yea! everything is ok i test it by id DESC and its working Descending order. actually sequence is missing because of my date and time. Thanx Timothy!